# Add developer to App Engine Account

Tags: google-app-engine

I created an application on Google App Engine, using my Google account.

I have another developer who will be working on the project with me.

How can he deploy the app from his machine also, using his own Google account? I dont want to give him my password.

Answer (score 2):

In app settings go to "Permissions" page from left menu. There you can add new developer's email and set permission for him("Owner" or "Developer" or Viewer).
Than he will receive notice on e-mail with accepting link.
After approving he will be able to work with your app with own account.